# cant download android LVL

Tags: android-lvl

I'm having trouble downloading the Licence Verification Library from the android SDK manager.

It's just not there in the list of things to get.  I have dl-ssl.google.com as the add-on site.  I get a message after the SDK spends a lot of time trying to download the list of possible updates: which ends in addon.xml.  For me everything else works in eclispe, I can build apps, run them on the emulator, debug on my actual phone.  I have also been able to add more recent android platform sdks to my environment.  Am I doing something wrong?  Here is the bit from the log:

```
Fetching ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml  
Validate XML  
Fetched Add-ons List successfully  
Fetching URL: ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml  
Validate XML: ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml  
Parse XML:    ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml  
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)  
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4  
  <-- SNIP -->  
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1  
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 1  
  Found Android Support package, revision 6  
Fetching URL: ://dl-ssl.google.com  
Validate XML: ://dl-ssl.google.com/addon.xml  
Failed to fetch URL ://dl-ssl.google.com/addon.xml, reason: addon.xml  
Done loading packages.
```

Comment: OK, I got it to work after 3 hours ... upgraded Android SDK tools from rev14 to rev 16.  Shut down eclipse and ran up SDK Manager from command line and it found the LVL package (Google Market Licensing package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I　don't know the reason.My eclipse is 3.7(Indigo),and my sdk tool is r16.But in the sdk manager i can't find the library,but when i try to find it in the sdk r17,it's just shown in the download list.Thanks god,i wish it can help you.

Comment: Thnx upgrade to r16 did it for me.